# Can we update the array collection in foreach loop?

Tags: powershell-3.0

```
$DLs="I have a collection of DLs in here"
```

Each DL might have Sub-DLs as members; Hence, I'm using foreach loop and updating the list in the loop as below.

```
foreach ($ML in $DLs) {

   $Temp=Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$ML" | select Name, RecipientType
   $DLs+=($Temp | Where-Object{$_."RecipientType" -eq "MailUniversalDistributionGroup" -or $_."RecipientType" -eq "DynamicDistributionGroup"})."Name"
}
```

As far as my understanding, PowerShell is suppose to check the DLs which are added in the end but it doesn't do that.

Can someone provide me a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understating , Foreach uses a automatic variable `$Foreach` inside the loop. so What ever is et to `$DL` here will get effected only once the loop is completed.

Here is a Psuedo code for example:

`foreach($t in $r){$t;$r=1;"r is $r";pause}`

[image]

**Update**

You can use `For` loop instead of `foreach`

example:

```
$r = 1..5

for($i = 0 ; $i -lt $r.count ; $i++)
{
        $r += 1..10 | Get-Random
    "current value is $($r[$i])"
    "r is $r"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Prasoon for explaining the cause of the problem; Is there any loop which we would read the updated items in the loop? It would be a great help!

Comment: Thank you Prasoon for your help.